# Can't make a POST request on Azure - EACCES

Tags: node.js, azure, axios, botframework

I have a Node application hosted in Azure as a Web App Bot. When I try to make a POST request with axios from that application, it gives me the following error:

```
 { Error: connect EACCES 172.30..etc etc
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
  errno: 'EACCES',
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.30..etc,etc',
  port: 443,
  config:
...
```

Locally, testing with Bot Framework Emulator it works like a charm.

Request:

```
let reqConfig = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": '123etc etc',
            "Content-Type": "application/json"            
        }
    }

axios.post("https://_______", body, reqConfig).then(r => {

        console.log(r);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('ERR: ', e);
    })
```

Comment: Can you post the code on how you are making the POST request with axios? Also, what version of Node you are on?

Comment: sure @ranusharao, i just edited the description.

Comment: @ranusharao it's node 10.14.1

Comment: EACESS is basically general socket error when 'Write' permission is denied on the socket file, or search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path  prefix. Does this work when you test on POSTMAN? Also, can you share the entire snippet of your debugging session?